# Non-prime power idempotents

Tags: abstract-algebra, idempotents

If $n$ is not a prime power then $\mathbb Z_n$ has an idempotent different than $[0]$ and $[1]$.

I don't really know how to start. How would you represent a non-prime power to prove that this is true?

Comment: Maybe try some examples of $n$ first?

Comment: Find $n=n_0n_1$ with $\gcd(n_0,n_1)$ relatively prime. Then choose $x\equiv 1\pmod{n_0}$ and $x\equiv 0\pmod{n_1}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You mean $\gcd(n_0,n_1)=1$ (or "$n_0,n_1$ relatively prime") of course....

Comment: You surely know the idempotents modulo $10$ (think squares). As @LordSharktheUnknown suggests, try some examples. You might notice that every idempotent has a factor in common with the base. There is a point of view which makes this obvious [there are no non-trivial idempotents in the group formed by the numbers co-prime to the base]. Think about the other properties idempotents must have.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how are you able to separate the mod($n_0n_1$) I get what to do after, but that's the step in stuck on

Answer (score 0):

This solution is divided in two parts

- Any product of rings has a nontrivial idempotent:

  *Proof*: Just notice that in $A\times B$ the element $x=(1,0)$ satisfies $x^2=x$.
- If $n=n_0n_1$ with $n_0, n_1$ relative primes then $\mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n_0}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_1}$

  *Proof*: This is the content of the Chinese remainder Theorem. For the proof consider the map
  \begin{align}\varphi:\mathbb{Z}&\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{n_0}\times \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \\ n&\mapsto (n \ \mathrm{mod} \ n_0, n \ \mathrm{mod} \ n_1)\end{align}
  This is a ring morphism whose kernel is the ideal $n\mathbb{Z}$. Hence by the Isomorphism theorem it induce the isomorphism above.

If you follow the proof carefully you will notice that the non trivial idempotent given is exactly the element $a\in \mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $\bar{\varphi}(a)=(1,0)$. That is, the element $a=[x]$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$x \ \mathrm{mod} \ n_0 =1 \text{ and } x \ \mathrm{mod} \ n_1 =1.$$

This is the solution of Thomas Andrews given in the comments so this answer is the same idea restated in another way.